# jquery retrieve ids of some elements and write them in an array

Tags: jquery, each, attr

I need to do the following: check if the 3rd td of a tr contains (exactly) 56 and then retrieve the id of the checkbox contained in the first td of that row.

```
<table>
    <tr class="bg">
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
            <input class="selected_ads" type="checkbox" id="43617" />
        </td>
        <td class="pa">text text</td>
        <td class="pa">56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bgwhite">
        <td nowrap="nowrap">
            <input class="selected_ads" type="checkbox" id="183578" />
        </td>
        <td class="pa">text</td>
        <td class="pa">56</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

($(".bg td:nth-child(3):contains('56')").length>0) or ($(".bgwhite td:nth-child(3):contains('56')").length>0) checks if the third cell contains the value I am looking for.

$(".pa").siblings().first().children("input[type='checkbox']")
gets me the checkbox, but I cannot retrieve its id.

Ideally my code would look like this:

```
var longlist = [];
for each ($(".bg td:nth-child(3):contains('56')").length>0) {

retrieve the id of $(".pa").siblings().first().children("input[type='checkbox']");
longlist.push(checkbox_id);
}
```

do the same for .bgwhite;

Ideally it would work too.

The most important thing for me would be to retrieve the id.

Comment: Most likely you are selecting the value of the first one in each iteration. Have you ever used the `.each` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.bg .pa:last').each(function(){

     if($(this).text() === '56'){

         longlist.push( $(this)
                           .closest('.bg')
                           .find('.selected_ads')
                           .attr('id') );
     }
});
```

Comment: @flish Np, let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

Given a jQuery element:

```
var $foo = $(".pa").siblings().first().children("input[type='checkbox']");
```

There are at least 4 ways to access its ID:

1. `var id = $foo[0].id;` – array dereferencing + [vanilla DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id)
2. `var id = $foo.get(0).id;` – http://api.jquery.com/get + [vanilla DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id)
3. `var id = $foo.attr('id');` – http://api.jquery.com/attr
4. `var id = $foo.prop('id');` – http://api.jquery.com/prop

Are you saying that you tried all of those and none worked?

Comment: no, I'm saying that while I understand what I am looking for, learning any language's syntax is painfully slow for me. But I am learning.